# Android Listview is not scrolling still not working

Tags: java, android, listview

Good day!

I have tried a lot of other posts on stackoverflow but it didn't work for me,
maybe its because I'm new to Android Development.

**My problem is as follow:**

[image]

**XML Layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="369dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Preview in Android Studio**:

[image]

**inside the onCreateView:**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { }
```

**Binding the listview:**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,     container, false);


  List<Events> list = Events.getEvents();
  int max = list.size();
  String[] Values = new String[max];
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

      Events e = list.get(i);
      Values[i] = e.getNaam();
  }

  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    rootView.getContext(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Values);

 listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

 return rootview;

 }
```

Another point is i can't click a list item wich is strange !

Any ideas or tips?
what do i wrong?

Kind Regards,
Stefan

Comment: try adding a scrollView to your listView

Comment: Same result not scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please set code of binding listview item please because i tried it and it scrolling successfully this prove that xml is ok and the problem could be in java code

Comment: try to bind items like this code and feedback me if it worked or not

Comment: Item binding is in the description

Comment: use this code please ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

Comment: remove root.getcontext and replace it with getapplicaitoncontext or Activityname.this

Comment: Dont have the option to use getapplication context im doing it in    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84946/discussion-between-salah-nour-eldin-and-stefan-van-de-laarschot).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is your ListView big enough to enable scrolling?

Comment: Yes it is !  i even have to down scale it since out of memory exception was thrown

Comment: Can you show how you're populating your ListView please? The java part of the code.

Comment: Updated answer. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout>    
    <ScrollView>
         <ListView ...>

         </listView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You need to add a `LinearLayout` around the scrollview, that way the scrollview knows inside what it should scroll. If this doesn't work, replace the ListView with another LinearLayout and add your items to the LinearLayout. I'm not sure if a `View` is capable of scrolling at all. Try first option first, otherwise try the latter. I know the latter will work for sure since I used the exact same design myself in an app I'm developing.

Answer (score -2):

As already mentioned in the comment, you have to add a ScrollView around your ListView, e.g.:

```
<ScrollView>
     <ListView ....>
     </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Updated my post i tried that same result not scrolling Ty !

Comment: The list view is not inside the scroll view. Switch to the XML code and make sure that ListView is inside ScrollView